# proof following Bessel's inequality and Fourier series

Tags: inequality, fourier-series

Letting $a_n$ denote the coefficients in the Fourier cosine series of any function $f(x)$ on 
$(0,\pi)$ , how can I show that:

$\sum_{n=1}^N c_n^2 \le ||f∥^2$,  where $c_n$ are the Fourier constants of $f(x)$ that:

$ a_0^2   \over 2  $+ $ \sum_{n=1}^Na_n^2 \le $ $ 2\over π $ $\int_{0}^{π}(f(x))^2\,dx $,  $N = 1,2,3,4\dots$

now that looks better :)

Comment: To learn how to format decently, go to http://meta.matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/93/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference , otherwise not many will have the patience to read and decypher what you tried to write...

Comment: oh ok, thanks. gona check it out now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

But...this is only part of Bessel's inequality, isn't it? I mean, we have the (complete) orthonormal trigonometric system (basis) $\;\{u_n\}_{n\in\Bbb N}\;,\;\;u_n=\{1,\sin x,\cos x, \sin 2x,\cos2x,\ldots\}\;$ with which we work in Fourier series, so then denoting by $\;\langle,\rangle\;$ the usual inner product we get

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \langle f(x),u_n\rangle^2\le||f||^2$$

But using the usual notation from Fourier series the above is just

$$||f||^2\ge\sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n^2 $$

Comment: you are right, that is why, it says following from the bessel's inequality and on top of that. we need only consider, not the whole fourier series but the cosine series. i just dont see how to bring it out.

Comment: But that's what is shown above, @user1825142 ! The sum contains **both** the sine and cosine parts' coefficients, which squared are more or equal than *just* the sum of the cosines' coefficients...!

Comment: then with that, i guess it is all done, ain't it?